# Django: remove Decimal prefix from queryset annotated field, when requesting values

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

to be brief, i have this queryset:

```
monthly_revenue = list(Booking.objects.annotate(month=Month('created_at'))
                           .values('month')
                           .annotate(total=Sum('price'))
                           .order_by('month'))
```

this is what it is returning:

```
[{'month': 11, 'total': Decimal('4550.00')}]
```

the result is going to a js script to show a graph, and i need to remove the `Decimal()` prefix.
Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to remove "Decimal" prefix you could just define a specific output field in your annotation:

```
monthly_revenue = list(Booking.objects.annotate(month=Month('created_at'))
                           .values('month')
                           .annotate(total=Sum('price', output_field=FloatField()))
                           .order_by('month'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `Django` you can use `DjangoJSONEncoder` as follows:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

my_dict = [{'month': 11, 'total': Decimal('4550.00')}]
json_result = json.dumps(my_dict, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

But, keep in mind that `DjangoJSONEncoder` turns decimal into strings so the result would be:

```
[{"month": 11, "total": "4550.00"}]
```

If you navigate to `DjangoJSONEncoder` source code you find this:

```
elif isinstance(o, (decimal.Decimal, uuid.UUID, Promise)):
    return str(o)
```

Comment: i already had that encoder extended for models serialization, now i just adjusted it to convert decimal to float, i'll share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you could convert it to a type float, like this

```
monthly_revenue = list(Booking.objects.annotate(month=Month('created_at'))
                       .values('month')
                       .annotate(total=float(Sum('price')))
                       .order_by('month'))
```

Comment: i tried it earlier, it doesn't work it throws:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Sum'`

Comment: you could convert it to a float before calling the Sum function

Comment: cannot use `float` in query

`float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'F'`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found two solutions that worked for me:
Thanks to [@Ramy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3427252/ramy-m-mousa)'s answer, I overidden the `DjangoJSONEncoder`, to support the conversion of a Decimal to a float:

```
import decimal
import uuid
from django.utils.functional import Promise
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

class JsonDecimalToFloatEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
def default(self, o):
    if isinstance(o, (decimal.Decimal, uuid.UUID, Promise)):
        return float(o)
    return super().default(o)
```

and I used it as he mentioned:

```
monthly_revenue = list(Booking.objects.annotate(month=Month('created_at'))
                               .values('month')
                               .annotate(total=Sum('price'))
                               .order_by('month'))
json_result = json.dumps(monthly_revenue,cls=ExtendedEncoder)
json_result
'[{"month": 11, "total": 4550.0}]'
```

this solution requires more work on the server side, so i opted for the second solution of [@rossi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12445133/rossi) which does more work on the database rather than the server, and that's what the django's documentation suggest.

```
from django.db.models import FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

list(Booking.objects.annotate(month=Month('created_at'))
                              .values('month')                                
                              .annotate(total_as_f=Cast('total', 
                               output_field=FloatField()))
                              .order_by('month'))

[{'month': 11, 'total': Decimal('4550.00'), 'total_as_f': 4550.0}]
```

hope this will help anyone in the futur.