# How to show in Django queryset dict-key and -values seperately in template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset, django-template-filters

I have the this output in the browser from HTML template:

```
{'coin__name': 'Bitcoin', 'total': Decimal('1498824')}
{'coin__name': 'Ripple', 'total': Decimal('335227')}
```

How can I show in an html template separately the key and the value(without saying Decimal)?

**Desired outcome**:

```
Bitcoin, 1498824
Ripple , 335227
```

I provide the query and the html template below:

**views.py:**

```
test =  filtered_transaction_query_by_user.values('coin__name').annotate( total = (Sum('trade_price' ) * Sum('number_of_coins'))).order_by('-total')
```

**template.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>Current dict pair</th>
    <th>Just the name of the crypto</th>
    <th>Just the price of the crypto</th>
</tr>
{% for item in test %}
<tr> 
    
    <td>{{ item }}</td>   
    <td>{{ }}</td>
    <td>{{ }}</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What does `item.0` and `item.1` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update template with below code:

```
            {{ test }}   <!--  test is list of dictonaries --> 
            <br>
            {% for item in test %} <!-- Loop to get each item(sub dictonary) from list-->
                <br>
                     {% for key,value in item.items %} <!-- Getting key values pairs from each sub dictonary item --> 
                        {% if forloop.last %} <!-- Checking if last iteration of loop just to add "::" after each value --> 
                            {{ value }} <!-- only displying values not keys from each sub dictionary -->
                        {%else%}
                            {{value }} , 
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                  
            {% endfor %}
```

**Refer to this answer for removing decimal from result.**
[Django: remove Decimal prefix from queryset annotated field, when requesting values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786096/django-remove-decimal-prefix-from-queryset-annotated-field-when-requesting-val)

Comment: Thank you @Ashish Nautiyal. :) However, I was trying to make it appear in a neat table. I could not because all coin-value pairs appear in one column. Can you please suggest how shall I modify the table? If i instert  `<td>{{ value }}</td>` to the HTML code, all coin-value pairs appear in one column.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching both the key and the value from the dictionary in the loop:

```
{% for key, value in test.items %}
<tr> 
    <td>{{ key }}</td>   
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to format Decimal value [see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat)